# Using of Class type variables as generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I need to pass a series of Class type arguments with associated callbacks to a method without defining additional classes or interfaces.

I tried something like:

```
void foo(Map<Class, Function> callbacks){
    for(Class clazz : callbacks.keySet()){
        if(!(callbacks.get(clazz) instanceof Function<clazz, clazz>)){
            System.out.println("callback type mismatch");
        }
    }
    //(own logic)
}
```

or

```
void foo(List<<T>Map<Class<T>, Function<T, T>>> callbacks){
    ...
}
```

which is erroneous. Any ideas how to overcome this issue (or why it is not possible without additional classes)?

Comment: I don't get why you need to know class? Can you do just something like
 <T>void foo(Function<T> ...callback){...}

Comment: The book *Effective Java* has a whole chapter on what Bloch calls "Typesafe hetrogeneous containers" which is basically what you're trying to construct here.